# Double sided printing on HP Photosmart C4280 (All-in-One) on Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, printing, all-in-one

I am trying to use double sided printing with HP Photosmart on Mac OS 10.6.2. I've updated the printer driver and tried to change the paper handling configurations, but it didn't work.

Any ideas how I can get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [full user guide](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/manualCategory?product=3192753&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&cc=us), the c4280 does not support automatic duplex printing. see page 38 of said manual for instructions on manual duplex printing.